React Heatmap like GitHub Contributions calendar
After having trouble with a few Charting libraries I decided to implement my own GitHub style heatmap with react and React-Bootstrap. It actually works. Since it does not need to be extensible it only has the features that it needs. However I was wondering if the code quality can be improved. Selecting a tile inside the heatmap takes 4ms which is a bit slow. It is usable even in this condition but I was wondering how I could improve it. Also some parts regarding the labels feels a bit hardcoded but I did not know better. Any suggestion about any part of the code would be welcome.
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Stack } from "react-bootstrap";
import OverlayTrigger from "react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger";
import Tooltip from "react-bootstrap/Tooltip";
import CommitByDayList from "./CommitByDayList";

const TILE_SIZE = "13px";
const COLORS = ["#ededed", "#acd5f2", "#7fa8d1", "#49729b", "#254e77"];
function getColor(count) {
  if (count === 0) {
    return COLORS[0];
  } else if (count < 10) {
    return COLORS[1];
  } else if (count < 20) {
    return COLORS[2];
  } else if (count < 30) {
    return COLORS[3];
  } else {
    return COLORS[4];
  }
}

function removeTimeFromDate(date) {
  return date.split("T")[0];
}

function get_today() {
  return removeTimeFromDate(new Date().toISOString());
}

function arrayRotate(arr, count) {
  const len = arr.length;
  arr.push(...arr.splice(0, ((-count % len) + len) % len));
  return arr;
}

const today = get_today();

function Tile({ date, count, idx, setDate, setTileIndex, selected }) {
  const color = getColor(count);
  console.timeEnd("setdate");

  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      placement="top"
      overlay={(props) => (
        <Tooltip {...props}>
          {
            <div>
              <p className="mb-0 border-bottom">{date}</p>
              <p className="mb-0">{count}</p>
            </div>
          }
        </Tooltip>
      )}
    >
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          console.time("setdate");
          setDate(selected ? today : date);
          setTileIndex(selected ? -1 : idx);
        }}
        style={{
          width: TILE_SIZE,
          height: TILE_SIZE,
          backgroundColor: selected ? "red" : color,
        }}
        className="border border-1 border-light"
      ></div>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
}

export default function CustomHeatmap({ data, repoDict, setDate }) {
  const [tileIndex, setTileIndex] = useState(-1);
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(new Map());

  function countFrequencies(arr) {
    const map = arr.reduce(
      (acc, e) => acc.set(e, (acc.get(e) || 0) + 1),
      new Map()
    );
    return map;
  }

  function createYearArray() {
    let date = new Date();
    let this_week = date.getDay();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1 - (7 * 52 + this_week));
    let dates = [];
    for (let week = 0; week < 52; week++) {
      let days = [];
      for (let day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
        days.push(date.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      }
      dates.push(days);
    }
    let temp = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < this_week; index++) {
      temp.push(date.toISOString().split("T")[0]);
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    dates.push(temp);

    return dates;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const freqs = countFrequencies(
        data.map((data) => data.commitDate.split("T")[0])
      );

      setChartData(freqs);
    }
  }, [data]);

  const days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
  const monthNames = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];
  const monthsShifted = arrayRotate(
    monthNames,
    -1 * (new Date().getMonth() + 1)
  );
  const dates = createYearArray();

  return (
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-start">
      <div className=" d-flex flex-column" style={{}}>
        <Stack direction="horizontal">
          {/* Week labels */}
          <Stack className="me-2 mt-1">
            {days.map((day) => (
              <div style={{ height: TILE_SIZE, fontSize: "smaller" }}>
                <p className="font-monospace">{day}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Stack>

          {/* Heatmap Tiles */}
          {dates.map((week, outer_idx) => (
            <Stack className="pt-1">
              {week.map((week_date, inner_idx) => (
                <Tile
                  idx={inner_idx + outer_idx * 7}
                  date={week_date}
                  count={chartData.get(week_date) ?? 0}
                  setDate={setDate}
                  setTileIndex={setTileIndex}
                  selected={tileIndex === inner_idx + outer_idx * 7}
                ></Tile>
              ))}
            </Stack>
          ))}
        </Stack>

        {/* Month Labels  */}
        <Stack direction="horizontal">
          {/* This is only to pad the month label names according to the month label names */}
          <div className="me-2 invisible">
            <p className="font-monospace"></p>...
          </div>

          {monthsShifted.map((name) => (
            <p className="mx-auto">{name.slice(0, 3)}</p>
          ))}
        </Stack>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


Here is what it looks like


You mention 4ms, but your component rerenders all tiles on click - 4ms is excellent, to be honest (I can't reproduce that in CodeSandbox, though, my timings are less optimistic by orders of magnitude). Your Tile is relatively simple, but the effect of rerendering everything must accumulate - you can wrap it with React.memo and likely (measure first!) get a speedup. Also, what's your primary objective here - performance or engineering/readability? I can write some "doesn't look right to me" things regarding code style, but can hardly suggest anything beyond memoization for performance.
